# Finding the Fourier coefficient

Tags: fourier-series

Compute the Fourier coefficient of

$$f(t) = \frac{t}{2\pi} - \left[\frac{t}{2\pi}\right]$$ where $[t]$ is the largest integer smaller than $t$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\eqalign{
  & f(t) = {t \over {2\pi }} - \left\lfloor {{t \over {2\pi }}} \right\rfloor  = \left\{ {{t \over {2\pi }}} \right\}\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le f(t) < 1 \hfill \cr 
  f(t + 2\pi ) = f(t) \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

So $f(t)$ is a [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) of period $2 \pi$, avg $1/2$, amplitude $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$f(t)=g(t)+{1\over 2}$$where $g(t)=g(-t)$. Therefore $$f(t)={1\over 2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin nt$$
$$a_n={2\over \pi}\int_{0}^\pi {t\over 2\pi}\sin ntdt$$